# Differential Equations Problem Population with Birth and Death Rates

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential

The death rate in a colony of bees is proportional to the population, and without any new births, half of the bees would die in 20 days. However, the actual population of bees doubles in 30 days. Given that the birth rate of the bees is proportional to the population, find the proportionality constant.

I've tried using the equations with dP/dT=P(k1-k2) and such, and I got ln(2)/30, which is incorrect. Can someone please help me? I honestly have no clue where to go next and have been stuck on this problem for several days now.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Can you explain in more detail what you tried to get the wrong answer? For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes, what I'm confused about is how to create equations with the birth rates and death rates given when there is no numerical info about the population given. I got the equation dP/dT = P(k1-k2), and then I integrated both sides to get ln|p| = kt+C. Then I just plugged in a sample number for the population (100) to get ln|100| = k*0 + C, so in this case C = ln|100|. Then I used the fact that the population doubles in 30 days to get the equation ln|200| = 30*k + ln|100|, and I simplified that to get k = ln(2)/30, but its wrong.

Comment: You haven't used the information about the death rate anywhere, so the value you've gotten is for the combined birth and death rate.

Comment: Yes I realized that. But how can I include the information about the death rate into my calculations? That is where I am stuck.

Comment: I did something similar with plugging in ln|50| = 20k + ln|100| to try and get the death rate, and then I subtracted the simplified value for k (ln|0.5|/20) from ln|2|/30, but the value I got from that was ln(1/2)/60 which is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at the case where no bees are born. Then if $P(T)$ is the population after $T$ days, we have

$$\frac{dP}{dT} = -dT$$

where $d$ is the proportion of bees that die per day. This gives us $P(T) = P(0) e^{-dT}$, and knowing that $P(20) = \frac{1}{2}P(0)$ lets us calculate a value for $d$ (you don't even need to know what the starting population is, because the $P(0)$ terms will cancel each other out).

Then we need to introduce the birth rate, which makes the DE

$$\frac{dP}{dT} = (b - d)T$$

where $d$ is the value already calculated, and $b$ is the proportion of bees born per day. In this case, we get $P(T) = P(0)e^{(b - d)T}$, and we are told that $P(30) = 2P(0)$. You can use that to find a value for $b - d$, and hence for $b$.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I realized I did a simplification mistake